# Text flashing when updating tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Hello having a problem with python code and tkinter the text is updates and when it does it draws over the previous text so i am just redrawing the background to get around this issue and ran it to a a problem it flashes when it updates and was to eliminate the flash and make it seamless when it updates

Drawing text under #title #artist
Here is the example code

```
def MainLoading():

while True:
    try:
        # Album:
        # Artist:
        # Duration:
        # NumberOfTracks:
        # Title:
        # TrackNumber:

        print("HI")
        State = os.system('qdbus --system org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_' + MacAddress + '/player0 org.bluez.MediaPlayer1.Status')
        print(State)

        cmd = ['qdbus --system org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0/dev_' + MacAddress + '/player0 org.bluez.MediaPlayer1.Track']
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        cv.create_image(0, 0, image=bg_image, anchor='nw')

        #Album:
        Album = proc.stdout.readlines(1)

        #artist
        Artist=proc.stdout.readlines(1)
        print(Artist[0])
        cv.create_text(1920 / 2, 500, font=('Circular Book', 40), text=Artist[0], fill="white")

        #Duration
        Duration = proc.stdout.readlines(1)
        print(Duration[0])
        #dad cv.create_text(1920 / 2, 400, font=('Circular Book', 40), text=Duration[0], fill="white")
        testingdur=str(Duration[0].decode('utf-8'))
        print ("1")
        durationString = str(testingdur.replace("Duration: ",""))
        durationString = durationString.rstrip()
        #durationString = durationString.replace("\n", "")
        print("Duration is "+durationString)
        print ("2")
        durationInt = int(durationString)
        print("Duration int is "+str(durationInt))
        durationSeconds = durationInt/1000
        cv.create_text(1920 / 2, 400, font=('Circular Book', 40), text=str(durationSeconds), fill="white")

        #testingdur.replace("Duration:", "")
        #NumberOfTracks
        NumberOfTracks= proc.stdout.readlines(1)
        print ("3")

        #Title
        Title=proc.stdout.readlines(1)
        print("4")
        print(Title[0])
        print("5")
        #cv.create_image(0, 0, image=bg_image, anchor='nw')
        cv.create_text(1920/2, 300, font=('Circular Book', 40), text=Title[0],fill="white")
        print("6")
        time.sleep(5)


    except:
        #print("ERROR: "+sys.exc_info[0])
        cv.create_text(1920/2, 300, font=('Circular Book', 15), text="............", fill="white")
        time.sleep(3)
```

Threading code

```
MainTread = threading.Thread(target=MainLoading, daemon=True)
MainTread.start()
```

Comment: It is better to create the image and the texts in the main thread and update them in the while loop.

Comment: @acw1668 ok will do ill try this